# Java: New enum which is subset of an old enum

Tags: java, enums

In Java, is there any way to define a new enum from an existing enum? I want the following capabilities.

```
public enum A{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
public enum B{1, 2, 3, 4};
public enum C{3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

1, 2, 3 and all must be identical, i.e,

```
A.1 == B.1 = true
B.4 == C.4 = true
```

A real life example would be DAYS, WEEKDAYS, WEEKENDDAYS, LECTUREDAYS, PARTYDAYS and etc.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: In short no. Each enum member is a distinct object instance. You can get around this by using the equals method instead of ==

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis An real life example would be DAYS, WEEKDAYS, WEEKENDDAYS, LECTUREDAYS and etc.

Comment: By the way, Java happens to have an enum of days of the week: [`java.time.DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html). See [my Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39008574/642706) to a similar Question for more discussion and examples.

Answer (score 9):

You can't extend enums, but judging from your week/weekend days example it seems you may need to think about it a little differently. If we have `enum Days{ MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN }`, then think about the week/weekend days as follows:

```
EnumSet<Days> weekDays    = EnumSet.range(Days.MON, Days.FRI);
EnumSet<Days> weekendDays = EnumSet.range(Days.SAT, Days.SUN);
EnumSet<Days> partyDays   = EnumSet.of( Days.TUE, Days.THU );
```

Natural questions like "are any week days also party days?" could then be expressed as you expect:

```
!Collections.disjoint(weekDays, partyDays)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In this way, I wouldn't be able to ensure type safety. Lets say if I want to have following methods, scheduleParty(PartyDays day, Time t); or scheduleLecs(LectureDays day, Time t), ....EnumSet technique doesn't serve my purpose.

Comment: You could of course just treat this constraint as a precondition to be checked at runtime (throw an InvalidArgumentException on violation). Not everything can (or should) be done at compile time. Maybe in your case it does, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be to do something like:

```
public class EnumTest
{
  public enum A {
    X1(1), X2(2), X3(3), X4(4), X5(5), X6(6), X7(7), X8(8), X9(9);

    private final int value;
    public int getValue() { return this.value; }
    A(int value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }
  public enum B {
    X1(1), X2(2), X3(3), X4(4);
    private final int value;
    public int getValue() { return this.value; }
    B(int value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }
  public enum C {
    X3(3), X4(4), X5(5), X6(6), X7(7);

    private final int value;
    public int getValue() { return this.value; }
    C(int value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }

  public static void main()
  {
    A a;
    a = A.X1;
    B b;
    b = B.X1;
    if (b.getValue()==a.getValue()) {
      // do something
    }
  }
}
```

But, if you do that, you should be careful that you are actually using the type safety of Enums, otherwise why not just store all the values as integers?  Something like this, where each Enum value has some other meaning could be useful if you sometimes want to compare between Enums, but usually want to use the type-safety.  In your "DAYS, WEEKDAYS, WEEKENDDAYS, LECTUREDAYS" example, I'd make sure the internal value is something strongly typed such as a Java8 `java.time.DayOfWeek`.

Comment: "value" is private and something is wrong with the "main" (which class it belongs to?)

Comment: I didn't think the enclosing class would add much, but I'll include it for clarity.  The private members were accessible because they were part of an inner class, but I'll add getters as well to make it more general.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerated types in Java provide the ability to define additional properties and methods.

```
public enum DAY_INDICATOR {
  SUNDAY(1,true), MONDAY(2,false), TUESDAY(3,false), WEDNESDAY(4,false), THURSDAY(5,false), FRIDAY(6,false), SATURDAY(7,true)
  private final int dayNumber;
  private final bool weekendDay;
  public DAY_INDICATOR(int dn, bool wd) {
    dayNumber = dn;
    weekendDay = wd;
  }
  public bool isWeekendDay() {
    return weekendDay;
  }
  ... more accoutrements of an enumerated type
}
```

Now you can extend the underlying type with whatever predicates you need to distinguish members of the set of enumerated values according to your business rules.