# Create a custom collection of days-of-the-week in JAVA

Tags: java, calendar

I want a custom calendar like this:

```
enum TradingDays {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday};
```

Then I need to iterate over it and check if a particular enum element is the day of week TODAY. The problem is that the JAVA calendar does not match to days of week from my calendar. So:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

TradingDays.Monday is not equal to any of now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

So how do I assign Monday, Tuesday etc from my calendar TradingDays the same type (in this case an integer value) from the JAVA calendar?

P.S. I need to have that calendar TradingDays like that because it is then shown to the user so he/she chooses on which days to trade.

Comment: You need to create a mapping between your enum and `now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`

Comment: TradingDays.Monday.ordinal()

Comment: In fact ordinal() is great. This is it: never look for more complex solutions

Comment: `ordinal()` is not so great. It starts at 0 and is meant for internal use, as specified in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal()).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Set<DayOfWeek> tradingDays = EnumSet.range( DayOfWeek.MONDAY , DayOfWeek.FRIDAY ) ; // Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, & Fri.
Boolean todayIsTradingDay = tradingDays.contains( LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).getDayOfWeek() ) ;
```

## Details

This functionality is built into Java.

## `java.time.DayOfWeek` enum

Java includes the [`java.time.DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum.

Pass around objects of this enum rather than mere integers 1-7 to make your code more self-documenting, provide type-safety, and ensure a range of valid values.

```
invoices.printReportForDayOfWeek( DayOfWeek.MONDAY );
```

Numbering is 1-7 for Monday to Sunday, per [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

Get a localized name of the day by calling `getDisplayName`.

```
String output = DayOfWeek.MONDAY.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ;  // Or Locale.US, etc.
```

## Collection of day-of-week objects

To track multiple days of the week, use an `EnumSet` (implementation of [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)) or `EnumMap` (implementation of [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)).

```
Set<DayOfWeek> weekend = EnumSet.of( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY , DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) ;
…
DayOfWeek dowToday = 
    LocalDate
    .now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
    .getDayOfWeek() ;
Boolean todayIsWeekend = weekend.contains( dowToday ) ;
```

Or in the case of this Question specifically, a collection of the weekdays. Perhaps define as a static final constant if the definition does not change during execution of the app.

```
static final Set<DayOfWeek> tradingDays = EnumSet.of( DayOfWeek.MONDAY , DayOfWeek.TUESDAY , DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY , DayOfWeek.THURSDAY , DayOfWeek.FRIDAY ) ;
```

Or make that even shorter by defining an EnumSet as a range of enum objects defined in a sequential order. Specify MONDAY & FRIDAY and let `EnumSet` fill in the values in between. Use [`EnumSet.range`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#range-E-E-).

```
static final Set<DayOfWeek> tradingDays = EnumSet.range( DayOfWeek.MONDAY , DayOfWeek.FRIDAY ) ; // Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, & Fri.
```

Then test for today. Note that a time zone is crucial in determining the current date. For any given moment the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zoneId ) ;
DayOfWeek dowToday = today.getDayOfWeek() ;
Boolean todayIsTradingDay = tradingDays.contains( dowToday ).getDayOfWeek() ) ;
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a constructor inside your enum, like in this example:

```
    public enum Currency {
    PENNY(1),
    NICKLE(5),
    DIME(10),
    QUARTER(25);

     private final int value;
     
     private Currency(int value) {
         this.value=value;
     }
}
```

While iterating you can use coin.value like this:

```
for(Currency coin: Currency.values()){
        
        System.out.println(coin+" "+coin.value);
        if(coin.value==1){
            System.out.println("THIS is the PENNY");
        }
        
    }
```

Which output is:

> PENNY 1
>
> THIS is the PENNY
>
> NICKLE 5
>
> DIME 10
>
> QUARTER 25

Answer (score 0):

With `enum`s you can do a lot of things that probably are familiar to you:

File `TradingDays.java`:

```
public enum TradingDays {
    Monday(Calendar.MONDAY),
    Tuesday(Calendar.TUESDAY),
    Wednesday(Calendar.WEDNESDAY),
    Thursday(Calendar.THURSDAY),
    Friday(Calendar.FRIDAY);

    private int calendarValue;

    TradingDays(int calendarValue) {
        this.calendarValue = calendarValue;
    }

    public static TradingDays today() {
        return fromCalendarValue(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
    }

    public static TradingDays fromCalendarValue(int calendarValue) {
        for(TradingDays td : TradingDays.values()) {
            if(td.calendarValue == calendarValue) {
                return td;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(calendarValue + " is not a valid TradingDays calendarValue");
        // or simply return null
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor inside your enum which takes an int value:

public class CalendarMain {

```
enum TradingDays {
Monday(2), Tuesday(3), Wednesday(4), Thursday(5), Friday(6);

private int value;

private TradingDays(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}
};

public static void main(String[] args) {

Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

if (now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == TradingDays.Tuesday.value) {
    // Chose Wednesday as the day to trade
    System.out.println(now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
    System.out.println(TradingDays.Tuesday.value);
}
}
```

}